# How can we debug a java application that has been run as an exe file?

Tags: java, debugging, command-line-interface, remote-access, remote-debugging

I know we can remote debug with this command

java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 ClassName

But here I have made my main class into .jar and then into .exe

How can I remote debug the app and have it hit the breakpoints?

My .exe is working btw.

Thanks

Comment: How did you package your exe? You can add those arguments before packaging it

Comment: @geobreze converted my class into jar with eclipse and then used jar2exe software to convert it to exe

Comment: I think you need to add those options in your jar2exe config to allow remote debugging. https://www.jar2exe.com/createdexe/config/option

Comment: thanks but looks like there are limited parameters that jar2exe can provide
Like these https://imgur.com/a/CwDtWKZ

Comment: As I can see on this screenshot https://www.jar2exe.com/sites/default/files/images/snapshots/step7-configstep5.png (taken from here https://www.jar2exe.com/usage/wizard/stepoutput) you can paste every option you want. So try adding `option -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=11001` in this window

Comment: Thanks but after adding that my app doesn't function, tried many variations... with and without class etc